# How does a wallbox limit the charging current?

Tags: current-measurement, current-limiting

There are wallboxes (for EV charging) where the user can choose to set an upper limit for the charging current. This is useful if the user's PV doesn't deliver enough power. It allows the user to avoid paying for extra incoming grid energy.
Is it done by phase cutting or phase angle control?

Followup: Does a smart meter at home that has 2 separate readings, one for import power and one for export power (e.g. like in Germany,) calculate the effective current over a period to calculate the power?

Comment: The charging current to what appliance? An EV / car? A home battery? In both cases, the wall box will talk to the appliance, and the appliance will limit how much charging current it consumes.

Comment: Mean current has got no place in the calculation of power. Import current and export current doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: import : power from grid, export: power to grid (home has a PV). Wallbox charges an EV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EV charging uses a simple pilot signal to tell the car how much to draw.

The actual battery charger is on the car, and is large and water-cooled.  It obeys the pilot signal in real time.

The wall-unit "charger", actually called EVSE, is a very simple thing containing only an RCD/GFCI, a signal generator for that signal, and a relay/contactor to disconnect power from the cord.  **That's all**. Really. Tear one down and see.

The signal is a 1000 Hz square wave, with different duty cycles reflecting different "allowed current".  10% = 6 amps, 40% = 24 amps, etc. **The car's onboard charger must change on the fly to match changes in the signal**. The standard puts all the complexity *in the car*, and makes the EVSE wall unit "charger" very simple.  This favors innovation by the aftermarket.  You could make one with an Arduino.

### Add current transformers and change the signal!

So it's a rather simple thing to add another module that connects to *current transformers* clamped around your service wire(s), and adjusts the EV pilot signal "on the fly" toward an objective.  Just alter the square wave, and the charger on the car does all the heavy lifting.

It's not just for favorable electricity pricing. It can also be used for safety-certified EV Energy Management Systems to allow an EV charging installation to not overload the panel (Myenergi Zappi's Grid Limit feature), or for multiple EVs to share a single current allocation (Tesla Power Sharing), or whatever they come up with next :)

Comment: With an Arduino, literally. https://www.openevse.com/

Answer (score 3):

> There are wallboxes where the user can choose to set an upper limit for the charging current.

If you're talking about [simple EV charging stations using type 2 connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_2_connector), there is no charger in the wallbox. They send a signal to the charger in the car, telling it to adjust its power.

The charger itself most likely uses active power factor correction (which can be combined with active rectification or not) followed by high voltage DC-DC that adjusts the charging current. None of these use triacs or phase cutting.

> Does a smart meter at home that has 2 separate readings, one for import current and one for export current (e.g. like in Germany), calculate the mean current over a period to calculate the power?

I'll answer for the French smartmeter Linky. They use [energy metering ICs from ST](https://www.st.com/en/data-converters/metering-ics.html), you can find lots of details in the datasheet. These measure instantaneous current and voltage at a sample rate that is much higher than mains frequency, then multiply the two to calculate instantaneous power, and integrate to get active and reactive energy. This method works with any current waveform, not just sine waves.

Note "averaging current" makes no sense as others said in the comments. In AC the average of pretty much anything except power is always zero. In fact having a non-zero average current would mean there is DC added on top of the AC, and that's not good because transformers have a strong dislike for DC. Instantaneous power is the product of instantaneous current and voltage. Energy (kWh or Joules) is the integral of power.

Active power is measured and billed per-period. This has important consequences if you use solar, because you cannot count on the meter for averaging load power. The power company does not allow net metering, which means at the end of each 50Hz period:

- If active energy was imported into the house, it is added to the billing counter.
- If active energy was exported to the grid, it is added to a separate "export" counter.

If you use a triac to switch on a 1kW load on every even period, then switch it off on every odd period, average power will be 500W, but actual active power is 1kW for one period, then 0W for the next, etc.

If solar PV produces 500W, then the meter will measure 500W import when the load is on, and 500W export when the load is off. Without net metering, this means the 500W will be billed on periods when the load is on, which is half the time, but it will not be refunded on periods when the load is off!

So if you want to adjust load power to correspond to PV production, for example to power a water heater, you can't use low-harmonic clean and cheap "slow PWM" with a triac that lets through whole mains periods. You either have to use a dirty phase-cut triac which makes a ton of harmonics and noise, or an expensive "pure sinewave" dimmer. The car's charger must have power factor correction, so it will draw clean sinewave current.